# selected attribute between <option tags in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I'm looking for some guidance here where I've struggled to get working.
I have an associative array with the following options:

```
$options_format [] = [
    'name' => 'Audio',
    'type' => 'Audio',
];

$options_format [] = [
    'name' => 'EBook',
    'type' => 'EBook',
];

$options_format [] = [
    'name' => 'Hardcover',
    'type' => 'Hardcover',
];

$options_format [] = [
    'name' => 'Paperback',
    'type' => 'Paperback',
];
```

The following for each loop then walks through the array to output the html:

```
<?php 
    $select = 'selected';
    foreach ($options_format as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option value="' . $value['name'] . '"' . (isset($format) && $format == $value['name']) {  "$select"  };
        echo ">" . $value['name'];
        echo '</option>' . "\n";
    }
?>
```

The `$format` variable hold the value for which ever is selected and it will then check if the `$format` variable is set. But what I'm trying to do is if the form entry has a validation error, it will retain the value of what the user had selected previously.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

```
$select = 'selected';
foreach ($options_format as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value['name'] . '"' . ((isset($format) && $format == $value['name']) ? "$select" : "")  ;
    echo ">" . $value['name'];
    echo '</option>' . "\n";
}
```

The way you write your ternary operator:

`((isset($format) && $format == $value['name']) ? "$select" : "")`

Assuming that `$format` holds the value of your `$_POST['select_field_name']`.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was on about, thanks very much I will check this when I get in an let you know :) thanks radu

Comment: @DeveloperJay Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: it solved the answer, and worked how it should, now the $format variable is retaining the value if there is an error within the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can change $format with your required value.

```
<?php

$options_format [] = [
    'name' => 'Audio',
    'type' => 'Audio',
];

$options_format [] = [
    'name' => 'EBook',
    'type' => 'EBook',
];

$options_format [] = [
    'name' => 'Hardcover',
    'type' => 'Hardcover',
];

$options_format [] = [
    'name' => 'Paperback',
    'type' => 'Paperback',
];
$format = "Hardcover";
 $select = 'selected';
echo "<select>";

    foreach ($options_format as $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value='".$value['name'] ."' ";
        if($value['name']==$format) 
           echo $select. ">";

        else
            echo ">";

       echo $value['name'] .'</option>' . "\n";
    }
echo "</select>";

?>
```